# Select Image on tapped gesture in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

How can i select image on tapped gesture. I want to add another image same as I have tapped on . If i have 3 images and if I have tapped 2nd one then it will dynamically add 4th image that will be same as 2nd one.

```
UIImage *image = [[info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"] retain];

    UIView *holderView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width/4, image.size.height/4)];
    UIImageView *imageview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:[holderView frame]];


UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapped:)];
    [tapRecognizer setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
    [tapRecognizer setDelegate:self];
    [holderView addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];

-(void)tapped:(id)sender {

    [[[(UITapGestureRecognizer*)sender view] layer] removeAllAnimations];
    NSLog(@"Tapped");
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:[(UITapGestureRecognizer*)sender view]];
    UIImageView *image = (UIImageView *)[(UITapGestureRecognizer*)sender view];
    [self.view addSubview:image];
}
```

I am using `[(UITapGestureRecognizer*)sender view]]` to get that view. But I cant. And on tapped I want to add that image which I have tapped.

Comment: What is your `holderView `? You seem to assign a gesture recognizer to each image?

Comment: i have edited my question u can see now my holdView.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is with your tapped method. When you write `(UIImageView *)[(UITapGestureRecognizer*)sender view];` you'll get the same added `imageView` and it's frame will be same as when it was added. You are then adding it using `addSubview`, If you do so it'll be added at the same position that it was added previously.

Just change your `tapped` like:

```
-(void)tapped:(id)sender
{
  [[[(UITapGestureRecognizer*)sender view] layer] removeAllAnimations];
  UIImageView *imgView = (UIImageView *)[(UITapGestureRecognizer*)sender view];
  UIImageView *imageview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:yourFrame]; //Set the next frame for the image view
  imageView.image = imgView.image;
  [self.view addSubview:imageView];
  [imageView release];
  imageView = nil;
}
```

Also add the gesture to UIImageView like:

`[imageview addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];` not to UIView.

Also set `imageview.userInteractionEnabled = YES;`

Comment: i have copied your code but its giving me error.  *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView image]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x68f4e30'

Comment: @Zohaib: I have edited my answer :) You need to add the gesture to UIImageView, not to UIView.

Comment: @Zohaib: now what's the issue ?

Comment: when i m using imageview(UIImageView) rather than holderview(UIView) my gesture recognizer is not working, i cant move my image. what i have done i have added an tag on both imageview and holderview and when i tapp i get holderview tag and from that tag i can use my imageView. so till now its working for me. :) Thank you

Comment: @Zohaib:because you need to set the imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES; Then the recognizer in UIImageView will work.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be confusing a `UIImage` with a `UIImageView`. A `UImageView` is a kind of `UIView` and can have one (and only one) superview.  If you want to know what image it holds you can use the `'image'` property. Then you can create a new `UIImageView` with the same `UIImage` as the one that tapped. Depending on your application you may need to resize its frame, and set it `contentMode`.

In any event, if the tap event is not being registered at all it is likely because `UIImageView` are by default `userInteractionEnabled=NO`, you must explicitly set it to be `YES` either in code, or in the XIB file.

Comment: i have set userInteractionEnabled=YES. i can move, rotate image but cant select .

Comment: Selection is not a default ability of UIViews.  UIControls and their subclasses have an idea of selection (which UIImageView is not a subclass of).  If you want to change its appearance after tapping it that is something that you will have to manage yourself.

Answer (score 1):

3 Problems:

1. You need a new `UIImageView` which holds the same `UIImage`, as Jon Rose pointed out.
2. You need to set the frame for the new `UIImageView`, like Midhun MP pointed out.
3. Both do miss the gesture recognizer logic, which is broken in your case, too. You can add a gesture recognizer to only one view at a time.

To solve 3, You either need (a) one recognizer for each `UIImageView`, or 
(b) you take one recognizer for the containing view, which is `self` in your case.

In case (a) you really should subclass `UIImageView` and implement the gesture handling there. In case (b), you'd add the recognizer to `self` and on the `tapped:` event you'd loop over the subviews to find the one that was tapped via

```
for(UIView* subject in self.subviews)
{
    CGPoint pointInSubjectsView = [recognizer locationInView:subject];
    BOOL pointInsideObject = [subject pointInside:pointInSubjectsView withEvent:nil];
    if(pointInsideObject){
        //subject is the tapped view. do the work...
    }
}
```

Your code suggests that you are doing animations which you want to cancel on tap and that the images may overlap and you want to bring the tapped image to the front? If this is the case, you probably should go with (a).

Good luck.

Comment: i dont want to stop animation i want to grab that imageView on tapped method. i want to tap on imageview and send that image view to another ViewController. but i cant grab that image view.

Comment: moving an image to a different view controller is yet another topic. possibly you should post a new question.